# how to solve this error when I install crf++ on mac?

Tags: python, macos, crf++

I tried to install crf++. I downloaded CRF++-0.58 from https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/#download. Then I followed the instructins on the official website of crf++.

I firstly entered the folder named CRF++-0.58. Then I typed following code in terminal:

`./configure`

And the result was:
`-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

Then I checked the file 'CRF++-0.58', there's no configure file. I don't know if it's the problem of crf++ or mine.

Comment: Download the tar file, the zips contain only binaries.

Comment: @hoefling Thank you so much! That's exactly my error.

Comment: @hoefling However another problem "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1" occured when I run the command "python setup.py install" in the file "python". Could you please also answer this question? The detail is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156374/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-crf